# Not able to view 'To' field using java mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to fetch/read my email using java mail API.
I am using following line to read the 'To' field

```
System.out.println("TO:" +  message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

And it is giving the following output :

```
TO:[Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@6e1567f1
```

where as I want the output like

```
xyz@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
Address[] recipients = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
for(Address address : recipients) {
   System.out.println("TO:" +  address.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.Io)) returns an array of message.
Retrive a value from message array sample code snippet.

Address[] recipients = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
for(Address address : recipients){
    System.out.println(address.toString());
}
```